# Angular - Filter ng-repeat by model value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a "Saving" model that contains a value called "Retailer".

I would like to create an ng-repeat that only shows items with the same "Retailer".

basically im trying to fix this

```
<div ng-repeat="saving in savings |  filter: { retailer: {{saving.retailer }} | limitTo:10">
```

But thats not correct.

How do i send in the "Saving" model value "Retailer" as the filter?

This seems to do the trick

```
<div ng-repeat="saving in savings | filter: { retailer: saving.retailer } | limitTo:10">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work AFAIK:

```
<div ng-repeat="saving in savings | filter: { retailer: 'Retailer' } | limitTo:10">
```

This should show those `saving` objects with a `retailer` property with value `Retailer`.

Usually this is used with an `input` and the user can filter the results.

Let's say we have this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="filterText">
```

You can filter the savings using this `input` the following way:

```
<div ng-repeat="saving in savings | filter: { retailer: filterText } | limitTo:10">
```

Comment: But how do i feed in the dynamic {{saving.retailer}} value? It needs to change depending on what "Saving" view page the user is on.

Comment: But you are enumerating the saving object just now. There is no point on filtering the current saving object, because it will always be true. You could do it this way by the way, but I don't see the point: `<div ng-repeat="saving in savings | filter: { retailer: saving.retailer } | limitTo:10">`

Comment: The whole point is that im showing a list of "Other savings from the same retailer" beside the saving. The answer is <div ng-repeat="saving in savings | filter: { retailer: saving.retailer } | limitTo:10"">

Comment: Do you have a `saving` object other than the one you just named in the `ng-repeat`? In the parent scope?